# Convert emoji title to unicode

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, emoji

I using [Twint](https://github.com/haccer/twint) to extract tweets resulted from a particular search (that gives me about 100k tweets). 
The problem is that Twint outputs the tweet content with the emoji title and not its specific unicode. This is one example:

```
@LulapeloBrasil presidente minha eterna gratidão a tudo que senhor fez, faz e fará ao nosso povo. Seguiremos lutando pelos nossos ideais! <Emoji: Heavy red heart>  <Emoji: Flexed biceps (dark skin tone)> #LulaLivre #EusouLula #LulaValeALuta #OcupaSaoBernardo
```

This is bad because I want to tokenize the tweet for further analysis (e.g. emoji usage) and a traditional tweet tokenizer (e.g. nltk TweetTokenizer) won't tokenize properly.

Do you have any suggestion about how can I convert these emojis titles to their respective unicode (I'm able to extract the titles only using `re`)?

Where can I get the data that [emojepedia](https://emojipedia.org/emojipedia/) uses? Or where can I download a list of all twitter emojis containing their unicode code and titles?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://emojipedia.org/twitter/

Comment: Yes, but I need a workable full list.

Comment: The other link that may be of use to you is this one: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f4aa

Comment: Ok, thanks. From your link there another link to https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/emoji-sequences.txt I Think I can work with this

Comment: Would someone please post that as an answer?
It helps SO to have an accepted answer to retire the question.

Comment: How about fix Twint or switch to a library which doesn't have this misfeature?

Answer (score 0):

I found these [files](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/) (with the help of @Philip Couling). It's a start to solve the problem, although some additional processing will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python package can maybe solve your problem

[emotlib - Python emoji + emoticon Library (<ゝω・)☆ ‍‍](https://github.com/steven5538/emotlib)

Is easy to use and support 2.7, 3.6 and support to Emoji 11.0.

But you still need to process the text first I think.